# Why is `obj.__del__()` not being called when collection containing object reference is deleted

Tags: python, multiprocessing, del

I am trying to build a `Process` subclass to utilize multiple GPUs in my desktop.

```py
class GPUProcess(mp.Process):
    used_ids: list[int] = []
    next_id: int = 0

    def __init__(self, *, target: Callable[[Any], Any], kwargs: Any):
        gpu_id = GPUProcess.next_id
        if gpu_id in GPUProcess.used_ids:
            raise RuntimeError(
                f"Attempt to reserve reserved processor {gpu_id} {self.used_ids=}"
            )
        GPUProcess.next_id += 1
        GPUProcess.used_ids.append(gpu_id)
        self._gpu_id = gpu_id

        # Define target process func with contant gpu_id
        def _target(**_target_kwargs):
            target(
                **_target_kwargs,
                gpu_id=self.gpu_id,
            )
        super(GPUProcess, self).__init__(target=_target, kwargs=kwargs)

    @property
    def gpu_id(self):
        return self._gpu_id

    def __del__(self):
        GPUProcess.used_ids.remove(self.gpu_id)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"<{type(self)} gpu_id={self.gpu_id} hash={hash(self)}>"
# Test creation
def test_process_creation():
    # Expect two gpus
    def dummy_func(*args):
        return args
    processes = []
    for _ in range(2):
        p = GPUProcess(
            target=dummy_func,
            kwargs=dict(a=("a", "b", "c")),
        )
        processes.append(p)
    
    for p in processes:
        p.start()

    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    del processes

    assert GPUProcess.used_ids == [], f"{GPUProcess.used_ids=}!=[]"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_process_creation()
```

`__del__` is not called for the second process.

`AssertionError: GPUProcess.used_ids=[1]!=[]`

Why is the second `__del__` not called?

Later, I'd utilize this class with `mp.Pool` to run a large set of payloads using one `GPUProcess` per my GPU and a function that uses `gpu_id` keyword to decide utilized device. Is this even sensible approach in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that `__del__` is not being called because the variable `p` from the previous for loop is still referencing the second process object

`object.__del__` is not guaranteed to be called when `del object` is called, as per [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__).

`object.__del__` is called when the reference count of the object is 0.

The `del` keyword reduces the reference count of the object by 1.

So you could resolve this by setting `p = None` or `del p` before calling the assertion to remove that reference, or call the assertion after exiting the `test_process_creation()` function, as that will remove all the reference counts from that stack level.

I found [this video from the mCoding channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IFjuQmlwXgU) to be very informative about `__del__` and how NOT to use it.

As an aside, I will note that while testing your code with those changes I found a couple of issues you will need to resolve:

1. After passing the assertion, I ran into the error `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`.  Your `__del__()` method should
   either use a try/except, or check if self.gpu_id is in the list
   before removing it.
2. In `test_process_creation()` you defined the dummy function as `dummy_func(*args)`, but the test processes you created specifically have keyword arguments defined with `kwargs=dict(a=("a", "b", "c"))`.  This will cause the exception `TypeError: test_process_creation.<locals>.dummy_func() got an unexpected keyword argument 'a'`.  The simplest solution would be to change the definition to `dummy_func(**kwargs)`

Comment: Of course. Stupid of me. Do you have any opinion on the general approach to the problem?

Comment: @vahvero  The problem of tracking and cleaning up the process IDs?  Or the question asked in the last paragraph about whether this is a sensible approach?  I haven't done much multiprocessing in Python so I can't give a strong opinion on that.  It may be worth asking as a separate question whether the approach is ok (there may even be an existing question out there).  The one suggestion I would have is to consider tracking the used gpu_ids in a set instead of a list.  As all the gpu are ints, they are hashable, and adding and removing elements from a set is O(1)

Comment: @vahvero don't use `__del__` for this at all, use a *context manager*

Comment: I do not think that is possible as the process must be used by the mp.Pool